# Rewrite url with .htaccess based on GET parameters

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to rewrite the following url pattern:

> `http://example.com/some/inner/page?param1=test&lang=en`

becomes

> `http://example.com/en/some/inner/page?param1=test`

. So basically I want to take the "lang" get parameter and put it at the begginning of url. I know I have to use RewriteRule in the .htaccess but what is the pattern that has to be written ? Note that I also need it to work for both `?lang=en` and `?some-parameter=test&lang=en`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this rule as your top most rule in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?(.*&)?lang=([^&]+)&?(\S*)\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%2%{REQUEST_URI}?%1%3 [R=301,NE,L]
```

This will remove `lang=` parameter from anywhere in query string and redirect using value of same parameter at the front.